# Simple question on installing a Groovy package from source

Tags: ros, diagnostics, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install the new version of diagnostics from source to my groovy.
I have backed up and deleted the version of diagnostics that was in my src folder and cloned the current version of diagnostics from the git repo. Before this I made sure that catkin_make_isolated worked.
After cloning the current version of diagnostics to groovy, Catkin_make_isolated gave me the following error:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'diagnostics'
==> Building with env: '/media/home/ros/devel_isolated/cpp_common/env.sh'
==> cmake /media/home/ros/src/diagnostics/diagnostics -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/media/home/ros/devel_isolated/diagnostics -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/media/home/ros/install_isolated in '/media/home/ros/build_isolated/diagnostics'
CMake Error: The source "/media/home/ros/src/diagnostics/diagnostics/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "/media/home/ros/build_isolated/diagnostics/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.
<== Failed to process package 'diagnostics':
  Command '/media/home/ros/devel_isolated/cpp_common/env.sh cmake /media/home/ros/src/diagnostics/diagnostics -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/media/home/ros/devel_isolated/diagnostics -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/media/home/ros/install_isolated' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /media/home/ros/build_isolated/diagnostics && /media/home/ros/devel_isolated/cpp_common/env.sh cmake /media/home/ros/src/diagnostics/diagnostics -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/media/home/ros/devel_isolated/diagnostics -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/media/home/ros/install_isolated
```

Should I delete the old versions of diagnostics from the build_isolated directory also?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186525/simple-question-on-installing-a-groovy-package-from-source./) by [goshawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18870/goshawk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out!
I just needed to delete the old built diagnostics file in the build_isolated folder.

---

Originally posted by [goshawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18870/goshawk/) with karma: 70 on 2014-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0